# Change date format on data from CSV before importing to database

Tags: php, database, csv, ms-access

I ran to some difficulties. I have application, that is reading CSV file data, and importing it to Access database. the problem is - date format in CSV file - I want to change it to Year/Month/Date. For that I need to know how to format it, before importing?

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $i=0;
            require "connection.php";
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
                echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
            }
            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
            $import=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
                    dateandtime,
                    lastname,
                    firstname,
                    paidtime,
                    approvedtime,
                    notadhering)VALUES(
                    ?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000,',',"'")) !== FALSE) {
                if($i>0) {
                $data = str_replace('"', '', $data);
                $data = str_replace('00:00', '', $data);
                $data = str_replace('0:00', '', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/01', '/1', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/02', '/2', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/03', '/3', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/04', '/4', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/05', '/5', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/06', '/6', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/07', '/7', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/08', '/8', $data);
                $data = str_replace('/09', '/9', $data);

                $import->bindParam(1, $data[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(2, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(3, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(4, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(5, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(6, $data[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                str_replace('"',' ',$data);
                $import->execute();
                }
                $i++;

            }
            $removal=$db->prepare("delete FROM adherence WHERE approvedtime = '0' OR notadhering IS NULL");
            $removal->execute();

            fclose($handle);
        }
```

[See a screenshot of the CSV file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oti6M.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
        require "connection.php";
        $getdata = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT dateandtime FROM adherence ORDER BY dateandtime"); 
        $getdata->execute(); 
        $infodate = $getdata->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $myinfoDate =  date( "Y/n/j", strtotime($infodate));
            ?>
            <form name='add' method="POST">
                <select name="late" id="late">
                <?php foreach ($myinfoDate as $row): ?>
                <option><?=$row["dateandtime"]?></option>            
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
                <input type='submit' name='submitlate'/>
            </form>
```

In here I try to get info from database with dates (without time). It gives error: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string.
How to handle this one? I have some problems understanding this...

Comment: What is the current format in the csv file?

Comment: I have embedded the image into the question that the OP linked to. It demonstrates the CSV format to be d/m/yyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do those string replaces... strtotime() can convert most strings to date...

```
$myDate =  date("Y/n/j",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data[0])));
$import->bindParam(1, $myDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for assistance!

Comment: Just one more thing - for some reason, in database - month and day swiched places, and has time like 00:00:00 possible to remove it?

Comment: i've updated my answer to fix the day/month mix up (your date is in european format, and mysql expects - instead of / ). You can set your column type to be date instead of timestamp if you don't want the 00:00:00 , but leaving it there shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Actually now it is not working. It shows all dates as: 1970.01.01

Comment: Yes, and it has time in it as 00:00.

Comment: 1/4/2015 0:00,  - it is 1st day of 4th month, 2015 year

Comment: can you paste more dates from your csv file, i need to understand the format your dates are in...

Comment: 1/4/2015 0:00,name,lastname,data,moredata,evenmoredata /end of line/
2/4/2015 0:00,name,lastname,data,moredata,evenmoredata /end of line/
3/4/2015 0:00,name,lastname,data,moredata,evenmoredata /end of line/
4/4/2015 0:00,name,lastname,data,moredata,evenmoredata /end of line/

Goes like that for every day

Comment: i just realized my last edit had a mistake and i had written and extra strtotime... can you try now.

Comment: Works perfectly! Now I just need to figure out how to remove time from these fields, because it is not shown in database, but it is being shown when trying to echo days list. Still - you are today's hero :)

Comment: don't worry what is in the database, when you are outputting the dates you can use strtotime as well.... `echo date( "Y/n/j", strotime($dateFromDB));` see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to customize the date format

Comment: Please check EDIT of post - if you have will to assist a little more.

Comment: you are requesting an associative array not a single value result.... try `$myinfoDate =  date( "Y/n/j", strtotime($infodate['dateandtime']));`

Comment: It gives error: Notice: Undefined index: dateandtime

Comment: go back to your old code and just change this `$row["dateandtime"]` to `date( "Y/n/j", strtotime($row["dateandtime"] ));`

Comment: It does not show any time anymore, But Now I'm unable to get any data from database - it says: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: -3030 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (SQLExecute[-3030] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)'

Comment: i would suggest you create a separate question for this MS Access related problem, unfortunately i am not that well versed with it :(

Comment: Actually it was working before making these changes in php :) Still -thanks for a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

If the csv format is m/d/y then you can just use strtotime()

```
$date = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($data['0']));
```

But if it is d/m/y then you would need to process the string because strtotime() assumes European date formats with 2 digit year to be y-m-d, so you would need to process with something like

```
// split to date and time bits
$bits = explode(" ", $data['0']);
// split the date into day month year (assumed)
$dateBits = explode("/", $bits['0']);
// split the time into hour minute
$timeBits = explode(":", $bits['1']);
// rebuild the time from the bits
$new = mktime($timeBits['0'], $timeBits['1'], 0, $dateBits['1'], $dateBits['0'], $dateBits['2']);
$date = date("Y/m/d", $new);
```